# iOS jailbreak: simple alert is not getting displayed in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

I am newbie to jailbreak tweak development.Now i just want to get alert dialog when i will get my `springboard` loaded for first time.

### Tweak.mx

```
%hook Springboard

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(id)application {
    %orig;

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome" message:@"Hello akash " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanx" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release]
  }

%end
```

### Makefile

```
include theos/makefiles/common.mk

ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64

test_FRAMEWORKS= UIKit

TWEAK_NAME = test
test_FILES = Tweak.xm

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk

after-install::
    install.exec "killall -9 SpringBoard"
```

So here I could compile this tweak properly,and also my iphone getting respring.So at this point I should get this alert,But I am not getting anything on screen.What step I am missing

> I am using `iPhone 5s` with `ios 7.1.2`

**Edit**

I could see console output which logs below error

```
<Error>: MS:Error: dlopen(/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/test.dylib, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/test.dylib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

And then i also see its filetype using `file test.dylib`

```
test.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
test.dylib (for architecture armv7):    Mach-O dynamically linked shared library arm
test.dylib (for architecture armv7s):   Mach-O dynamically linked shared library arm
```

That means,I am not getting `arm64 architecture` thats why its failing on my `iPhone 5s` because its `64bit`,can anyone point out how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found **solution**,

Just need to put `ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64` before 
 `include theos/makefiles/common.mk`

---

So now my **makefile** is as

```
ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64 

include theos/makefiles/common.mk


test_FRAMEWORKS= UIKit

TWEAK_NAME = test
test_FILES = Tweak.xm

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk

after-install::
    install.exec "killall -9 SpringBoard"
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out, and thanks for posting the solution as well!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are hooking the wrong function? The function you're looking for is

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Comment: i don't think so i should hook this method,but `applicationDidFinishLaunching ` this is working